# Weird picture Distortions

Tags: lubuntu, toshiba

For some reason even after I updated the graphic drivers. I still get this weird picture on  every video or moving advertisement. It's a purple-green pixel texture that's almost impossible to recognize what the original picture looked like (not enough rep so I cant post an example). I've tried installing and updating the drivers, and it's still the same picture. I'm currently using a Toshiba Satellite A45-S150, Lubuntu 13.04. Is there a problem with the specific chipset, or is there a driver that I'm missing

Answer (score 0):

gremlins?

1. try another browser and see if they still appear
2. reinstall your current browser.
3. toggle the hardware acceleration setting.
4. be careful if you have liquids around

have a good one.

Comment: Hey this is really late but thanks for the answer, unfortunately my laptops AC power cord and battery have died on me so I cannot use it any more due to no parts for it being sold any more (early 2000's laptop).